# create-react-app: What is the "On your Network" mean for when I run npm start

Tags: reactjs, networking, create-react-app

When I run `npm start` in the project I created using create-react-app I see options to open it via '**localhost**' or '**On your Network**'.

What does 'on your network' mean? Is my network my LAN? Does this mean my is project public to others when I run it?
I have only ever used localhost before so is there benefit to using the network option over the localhost?

Comment: LAN means Local Area Network, so it is your local network, and on your network means on your LAN.

Answer (score 0):

It simply means if you give someone *on your network* that IP, they can view your site *running on your localhost* as long as your network allows it. With screen sharing in every chat app these days, I'm not sure there's a much use for that specific use case, but that's what it does.